# Same template with different controllers on the same page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having issues with using the same template with different controllers on the same page in AngularJS.

Lets say I have a panel template PANEL which I use with controller A.

A has a method doSomething() which is in the scope. PANEL calls this method when I click on a panel button.

I would like to duplicate this panel with minor changes in the controller so I add another panel to this page, PANEL with controller B.

B also has this method doSomething().

I've noticed that when I click on the button in the panel which is attached to controller B (using a directive), it calls doSomething() in controller A. It's probably happens because both doSomething() of controllers A and B are in the scope which makes sense.

The question is how can I make it work properly?
I know I can do it with ng-if or some other why which affects the HTML but is there an elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing that springs to mind is to use ui-router and in your methods in your controllers, check which 'state' you're in and do something different for each one.

Ie. two states, panelA and panelB, in your methods, something like this:

```
method() {
  if ($state.current.name === 'panelA') {
    do_something_for_panel_A();
  }
  if ($state.current.name === 'panelB') {
    do_something_for_panel_B();
  }
}
```

Ofc, I would suggest having a separate template for each 'state', each with it's own controller. But design is individual and project based, so that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using 2 directives and setting the `scope` property to `true`.

My 2 directives:

```
angular.module('my-app')
.directive('panelOne', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'panel.html',
    controllerAs: 'panelCtrl',
    controller: 'PanelOneController',
    scope: true
  };
});
```

and

```
angular.module('my-app')
.directive('panelTwo', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'panel.html',
    controllerAs: 'panelCtrl',
    controller: 'PanelTwoController',
    scope: true
  };
});
```

Once I added `scope: true` each directive will only work inside its own scope. Both PanelOne and PanelTwo can be loaded on the same page without being taken over by another one.